# A consequence of the ideal theoretic version of Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $I_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, be comaximal ideals in a commutative ring $R$ and $I=\cap _{1\leq i \leq n}I_i$. Prove that $(R/I)^\times$ is isomorphic to $(R/I_1)^\times \times \cdots \times (R/I_n)^\times$. ($(R/I)^\times$ means the invertible elements of the quotient ring.)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. If $R$ and $S$ are isomorphic rings, then $R^\times\cong S^\times$ (unit group is functorial).
2. $(R\times S)^\times=R^\times\times S^\times$ (literally equals).

Comment: Category theory fans can prove 2. by nothing that $R \mapsto R^*$ has left adjoint $G \mapsto \mathbb{Z}[G]$, hence preserves limits. ;-)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg While I do like me some get-it-for-free by abstract nonsense, I think in this case it might be a tad excessive :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you "guess" what would be the natural map between $R/I$ and $R/I_1 \times R/I_2 \times \dots \times R/I_n $

> $\eta :R/I \rightarrow R/I_1 \times R/I_2 \times \dots \times R/I_n $ with 
>   $x+I\rightarrow (x+I_1,x+I_2,\dots,x+I_n)$

do you atleast see that $\eta$ is injective...

suppose $\eta(x+I)=0\in R/I_1 \times R/I_2 \times \dots \times R/I_n$

i.e., $(x+I_1,x+I_2,\dots,x+I_n)=(0+I_1,0+I_2,\dots,0+I_n)$

i.e., $x+I_1=0+I_1, x+I_2=0+I_2,\dots x+I_n=0+I_n$ i.e., $x\in I_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$

i.e.,  $x\in \cap_{1\leq i\leq n} I_i$ as we know that $\cap_{1\leq i\leq n} I_i=I$,we see that $x\in I$

i.e., $x+I=0+I$ i.e., $\eta$ is injective.

So, we now have a hope that it could "possibly be surjective" and thus ISOMORPHISM

(In above step I assume you know how to prove $\eta$ is homomorphism)

let us try proving this first for $n=2$ and hope induction works neatly...

we now thus assume $I_1,I_2$ are comaximal and $I=I_1\cap I_2$.

As they are comaximal, we have $R=I_1+I_2$ i.e, for some $x\in I_1, y\in I_2$ we have $x+y=1$

let us see where does $x\in I_1$ and $y\in I_2$ goes under $\eta$ we have $\eta (x)=(x+I_1,x+I_2)$...

As $x$ is already in $I_1$ we have $x+I_1=0+I_1$

as $x+y=1$ we have $x=1-y$ and thus $x+I_2=1-y+I_2$

we know that $y\in I_2$ thus $y+I_2=0+I_2$ i.e., $x+I_2=1-y+I_2=1+I_2$

So, we have $\eta(x)=(x+I_1,x+I_2)=(0+I_1,1+I_2)$

For similar reasons, we see that $\eta(y)=(y+I_1,y+I_2)=(1+I_1,0+I_2)$

Now, take an arbitrary element $(r_1+I_1,r_2+I_2) \in R/I_1\times R/I_2$

we ant to know where does $(r_1+I_1,r_2+I_2)$ comes from under $\eta$.

we have $(r_1+I_1,r_2+I_2)=(0+I_1,r_2+I_2)+(r_1+I_1,0+I_2)$

Now,

> $(0+I_1,r_2+I_2)=(r_2+I_1,r_2+I_2)(0+I_1,1+I_2)$
>   $(r_1+I_1,0+I_2)=(r_1+I_1,r_1+I_2)(1+I_1,0+I_2)$

So, $(r_1+I_1,r_2+I_2)=(r_2+I_1,r_2+I_2)(0+I_1,1+I_2)+(r_1+I_1,r_1+I_2)(1+I_1,0+I_2)$

and we know that $\eta(x)=(x+I_1,x+I_2)=(0+I_1,1+I_2)$ and $\eta(y)=(y+I_1,y+I_2)=(1+I_1,0+I_2)$

So, we now have

$(r_1+I_1,r_2+I_2)=(r_2+I_1,r_2+I_2)(0+I_1,1+I_2)+(r_1+I_1,r_1+I_2)(1+I_1,0+I_2)=\eta(r_2)\eta(x)+\eta(r_1)\eta(y)=\eta(r_2x+r_1y)$

So, $(r_1+I_1,r_2+I_2)$ comes from $r_2x+r_1y\in R$ (under $\eta$) .

Thus we see that $\eta : R/I \rightarrow R/I_1 \times R/I_2$ is surjective and hence ISOMORPHISM

(Injectivity is proved already and homomorphism is left as easy to see condition)

i.e., we have $R/I\cong R/I_1\times R/I_2$

Now, for induction process, if you have $I_i : 1\leq i\leq n$ the, take $I_1=I_1$ and $I_2\cap I_3\cap \dots I_n= I_m$ then you will get $R/I\cong R/I_1\times R/I_m$

now repreat the same for $m$ at last you will end up with the case that

$R/I\cong R/I_1 \times R/I_2 \times \dots \times R/I_n $ and thus, we are done.

P.S : as Mr.Alex says,

> If $R\cong S$ then $R^*\cong S^*$ 
>   $(R\times S)^*=R^* \times S^*$

and if we apply this to

$R/I\cong R/I_1 \times R/I_2 \times \dots \times R/I_n $

we get $(R/I)^*\cong (R/I_1)^* \times (R/I_2)^* \times \dots \times (R/I_n)^* $ and
now it is complete :)

I prefer using $R^*$ for invertible elements of $R$ and please excuse me if that bothers you :)